# Migrate complex svn into git (keep history, trunk and branches are not on the right places)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I looked for almost all similar questions, but none are match my "strange" structure of svn which I need to migrate.

So I need to migrate:

svnrepo:

```
ver_1.0/    
    | 
         trunk/
            | 
               Module_A
               Module_B
ver_1.5/
    |
         trunk/
            |
               Module_A  (svn copy from ver_1.0)
               Module_B  (svn copy from ver_1.0)
```

(Yes, it's strange and wrong)
So instead of branches - modules were just copied, to keep the history. 
If you open a history for ver1.5 Module_A - you will changes from ver1.0 and ver1.5.

Now I need to migrate all this into git but in correct way, so git repo looks like:

```
gitrepo:
Module_A
Module_B
```

with *history* (I assume that in this case I should recreate branches manually)

So what is the best way to achieve it ?

Should I migrate each version in local git repo and then merge it ? 
Can git svn handle this kind of config ? I tried to set "--trunk" - to latest version and version-folders as "--branches" but that didnt work.

Comment: My recommendation is to convert 2 times: `git svn clone -T ver_1.0/trunk && git svn clone -T ver_1.5/trunk` and then combine 2 git repositories.

Comment: Every trunk ideally boils down to master in git. So from the above it seems you would end up having a monolithic repo with moduleA and moduleB as folders within master of ver1.0 repo, and same structure for ver1.5 repo. A question i would ask is would the latest trunk suffice and only migrate that, as it would also have the history